# StackOverflowError after jsp url mapping

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have following `content/data.jsp` page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="../template/header.jsp"/>

<jsp:include page="../template/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

where `header.jsp` and `footer.jsp` are just plain html files. Works excellent. Then I add these lines to my `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>data</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/content/data.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>data</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I try to request `contextpath/data` instead of `contextpath/content/data.jsp`, I get following error stacktrace:

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-29) UT005023: Exception handling request to /contextpath/data: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:506) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:390) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:27) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

etc.. Full stacktrace is huge, but i'll write it if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was gone after using `<include-prelude>` and `<include-coda>` in web.xml instead of `<jsp:include>`-based template. I just added

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>/template/header.jspf</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>/template/footer.jspf</include-coda>

    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

to my `web.xml` and completely removed ugly repeating `<jsp:include page="../template/header.jsp"/>` and `<jsp:include page="../template/footer.jsp"/>` lines from jsp files. Now URL mapping works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

But I use the next structure in web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>NameServler</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Location..Packege</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>NameServler</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/NombredeAcesoalServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: jsp files use `<jsp-file>` property instead of `<servlet-class>`.